# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:

Tags: reactjs

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { App } from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

I am getting this error. Above is my index.js file.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Maybe `import App  from "./App";` if you have default export of the App component? Also check where App.js file is. if it's in the `scr`  directory path might be `import App  from "./src/App";`

Comment: both files (App.js) and (index.js) is in the same src directory

Comment: Kindly add the `App.js` code snippet. It will be easier for us to help you debug this issue. Thanks.